# Refresh the datagrid in endedit event using windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

1. bind the datagrid at form load.

   ```
   DataGrid1.DataSource = objBindinglist
   ```
2. Changed the value in datagrid

   ```
   DataGrid1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
      DataGridViewCell cell = null;

      if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
      {
        cell = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
       ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[sates.Index].Value = cell;
      }
   }
   ```
3. after edit i want to refresh the datagrid.

   ```
   private void DataGrid1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
     ((DataGridView)sender).DataSource = null;
     var lstDataSource = 
       ((BindingList<person>)(((DataGridView)sender).DataSource))
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.sates).ToList();
   objBindinglist = new BindingList<person>(lstDataSource);
   DataGrid1.DataSource = objBindinglist;
   ```
4. one bindinglist is declare at the top.

   ```
    BindingList<person> objBindinglist = new BindingList<person>();
   ```

Question:
 Is it possible to bind a refresh list to the bounded datagrid.
 when i give datasource is null in the endedit event it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are going to have a very hard time changing the DataSource in the EndEdit event because the grid most likely still needs this data.

If your goal is to simply resort the data, you would be much better off using the builtin sorting mechanism. When you configure your grid, set the column that you want the data to be sorted in in the `SortColumn` property and set the `SortOrder` property to `System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending`.

If the grid doesn't update correctly after editing is complete, just call the `Sort` method.

Comment: Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function